# Android - DataBinding with LiveData hold old values

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have DataBinding set and I use a ViewPager BindingAdapter to switch between screens:

`BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter("app:nextPageListener") fun nextPageListener(viewPager: ViewPager, next: Boolean?) {
  next ?: return
  if (next) viewPager.nextPage()
  else viewPager.previousPage()
}
```

`View Pager`

```
<ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:nextPageListener="@{viewModel.nextPageListener}"
    />
```

`viewModel.nextPageListener`

```
  private val _nextPageListener = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
  val nextPageListener: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _nextPageListener
```

My issue is if I call `_nextPageListener.postValue(true)` and go to the next page and at some point leave the screen, when I come back the `BindingAdapter` is automatically called with `true` which makes the pager go to the next page. so basically on all the following times the pager is opened on the second screen.

Not sure if it has anything to do with lifecycle, but if it helps this is what I have

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

Any idea how to fix this without some ugly workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use `Event` class.

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Now you can wrap your `LiveData` like this.

```
   private val _nextPageListener = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
val nextPageListener: LiveData<Event<Boolean>> get() = _nextPageListener
```

and final step in your activity.

```
yourVm.nextPageListener.observe(this, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                when (it) {

                  //get Your value here.
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't actually observe the `LiveData`, it's only meant to be used with the `DataBinding` views. I tried using `SingleLiveEvent` instead but with same results

Comment: The main reason behind this behaviour is that your previous `viewmodel` instance is not destroyed and yet you are trying to make another one. is your `viewmodel` provider code is in `oncreate` method?

Comment: I'm using Koin library to inject it, but you might be right